# Bootstrap Col Responsiveness making it relative/responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi how can i make this responsive even im resizing the browser it will look like the original thank you!

```
<section class="swag1 text-center foodft">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="our-prod1">
          <h2 class="section-heading" >Food for Thoughts</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 foodforimg">
        <img   src="img/start.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8"> 
        <div class="foodfort-sec">
          <p> Healthy Endings came to life with the best intentions to create all natural snacks, organic when possible, raw and vegan with absolutely no preservatives. We love to snack periodically through out the day and we're always working on creating the most delicious and nutritious snacks to satisfy those cravings.  "What fun is snacking if the snacks donít taste orgasmically good!"</p>
          <br />
          <p> Cherie Spencer, the founder and creator of Healthy Endings snacks received her certification as a Health Educator from the world renowned Hippocrates Health Institute in West Palm Beach, Florida and holds a Bachelors in Healthcare Administration from Florida Atlantic University. She also received a culinary certification from Atlantic County VoTech and holds a SafeServ Food Manager Certification/License. She is a holistic chef specializing in raw, living foods and loves to </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

css

```
.foodfort-sec {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Original:

[image]

Resized Img:

[image]

Comment: can you make a fiddle or something ?

Answer (score 1):

Your image tag need `.img-responsive`

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/start.jpg">
```

I hope that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the grey box is actually an image (going outside of its container when screen is being resized), then:

```
.foodforimg img {
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
}
```

should resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. https://jsfiddle.net/9946ntyb/

You can add the class 'img-responsive' to your image so that it automatically resizes.

```
<img class = 'img-responsive' src = 'img/start.jpg'>
```

A also your break tag is broken, only use

```
<br>
```